# Identify partition by mount point

Tags: linux, bash

How can we identify what partition a filesystem is mounted on in Linux when the partition is not directly referenced in `df` output?

For example, our system's `fdisk` output is:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        2550    20478976   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            2550       60736   467378176   83  Linux
/dev/sda3           60736       60801      523264   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

And the output from `df` is:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           20G  881M   18G   5% /
/dev/root        20G  881M   18G   5% /
devtmpfs        989M  216K  989M   1% /dev
/dev/sda2       443G  199M  420G   1% /home
tmpfs           990M     0  990M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/root        20G  881M   18G   5% /var/named/chroot/etc/named
/dev/root        20G  881M   18G   5% /var/named/chroot/var/named
/dev/root        20G  881M   18G   5% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf
/dev/root        20G  881M   18G   5% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.rfc1912.zones
/dev/root        20G  881M   18G   5% /var/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key
/dev/root        20G  881M   18G   5% /var/named/chroot/usr/lib64/bind
/dev/root        20G  881M   18G   5% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.iscdlv.key
/dev/root        20G  881M   18G   5% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.root.key
```

From that list the only obvious partition is `/dev/sda2`; for the others we can't see which partition they reside on (we want to do this via a bash script).

For example, we know that `/dev/root` is mounted on `/dev/sda1` as they both have the same 20GB size, but how can we identify this from a script?

Output from `ls -l /dev/root /dev/sda1`:

```
[root@server etc]# ls -l /dev/root /dev/sda1
ls: cannot access /dev/root: No such file or directory
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 May  7 14:16 /dev/sda1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That output is misleading.
You actually have 2 different filesystems mounted at `/`.

`rootfs` is the filesystem created by an initramfs. When the bootloaders loads the kernel, it has the ability to load an initramfs which gets unpacked into a tmpfs filesystem. This filesystem cannot be unmounted. When the initramfs is done doing its thing, it simply mounts the real root filesystem on top of it.

The reason why `df` shows it as 20gb is because it can't get to that tmpfs filesystem. When `df` goes to show the filesystems, it first gets a list of current mounts from `/etc/mtab`. This gives it 2 mounts using `/`. It then makes a `statfs()` syscall on each mountpoint. But since the current root filesystem sits on top of the tmpfs initramfs, it ends up statting the current root filesystem twice.

Additionally `/dev/root` is actually a symlink. To find out where it really points using a shell script, you can use `readlink -f /dev/root`.

---

Update: Ok, so in this case `readlink -f /dev/root` does not work as `/dev/root` does not exist any more. Because the initramfs is what mounted your real root filesystem, `/dev/root` would have existed there. But since the initramfs is buried, `/dev/root` is not there any more.

In this case it becomes much much more difficult.
What you can do is to use `stat` to get the device number for the mountpoint, and then search through `/dev` for that.

For example, on my system this yields:

```
$ stat --format '%D' /
fd00

$ stat --format '%02t%02T' /dev/mapper/sys-root
fd00

$ for device in $(blkid -o device); do 
>   [ "$(stat --format '%04D' /)" = "$(stat --format '%02t%02T' "$device")" ] && \
>     echo "$device" && \
>     break
> done
/dev/mapper/sys-root
```

Basically what this does is uses `stat` to get the device major and minor number of `/`. We then iterate through all known block devices looking for one with that same device major and minor.
It's not pretty, but basically the `/dev` entry has a different name, and so we have to search for it.

*This could be done more efficiently, but I wanted to keep the code simple*

Comment: Our script iterates through the disk's partitions, so if it's looking at `/dev/sda1` for example, how would we work out that the filesystem for that partition is `/`?

Comment: Output of `readlink -f /dev/root` is just `/dev/root`.

Comment: @Chris can you add `ls -l /dev/root /dev/sda1` to your question?

Comment: Output of that command added to question.

Comment: @Chris I updated the answer.

Comment: For what its worth, I think it'd be more reliable to search /proc/partition for the major and minor numbers. A /dev/ file for a mounted filesystem is not guaranteed to exist.

Comment: @etherfish there are merits to that as you indicate yes. However by the `blkid` output can be a little more meaningful. Like in my example, `blkid` gives me the `/dev/mapper` entries. `/proc/partitions` only shows me `dm-0`, `dm-1`, etc. Quite unhelpful. But still, it is another avenue, and may be more useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

/dev/root is a symlink to the real device. You should be able to get the location with either ls /dev/root, realink or looking for root= in /proc/cmdline.